# How to mix this this two ng-class sentences

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have this two ng-class sentences. How can I mix them into one:

ng-class="['step-0' + main.activeConnectStep]"

ng-class="{'active': main.activeConnectStep > 0 }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using array notation:

```
ng-class="['step-0' + main.activeConnectStep, main.activeConnectStep > 0 ? 'active' : '']"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ng-class="{'active': main.activeConnectStep > 0, 'step-0{{main.activeConnectStep}}': 1}"
```